# Sending emails in python while using PyHook in intervals

Tags: python, email, time, pyhook

I'm using pyHook to hook the keyboard and the mouse actions. A log of the hooks is being created while the program is running. I want to send the log to an email every 5 minutes - while the PunpMessages is still working and the hooking action is still running. I know how to send emails in python, however, I don't know how to do it every fixed interval.

Comment: Look into Polling function.

Comment: How is this connected to my problem? Are you talking about this? http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Answer (score 1):

you can try python schedulers to call your methods on given interval.

You may want to look at this module:
http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/